# How can I zip the contents of current directory minus all hidden files?

Tags: wildcards, zip

How can I zip up the contents (excluding hidden files and folders) of the folder I am currently in?

```
zip -r extension.xpi . -x "*/.*"
```

This is what I have so far, but I am still getting hidden files.

Comment: Do you mean hidden files in subfolders? Otherwise it's just `*` which by default does not include hidden files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `*/.*` will only include hidden files in subdirectories. but not in your current directory or subdirectories of subdirectories. try this `zip -r extension.xpi . -x ".*"` or that `zip -r extension.xpi . -x .\*`.

I guess the backslash should be the key, thats a quote from the manpage:

> Explicitly exclude the specified files, as in:
>
> ```
> zip -r foo foo -x \*.o
> ```
>
> which will include the contents of foo in foo.zip while excluding all the
>   files that end in .o.  The backslash avoids the shell filename substitution,
>   so that the name matching is performed by zip at all directory levels.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for the following test directory structure:

```
$ tree .
.
├── adir1
│   ├── afile1
│   ├── afile2
│   ├── afile3
│   └── afile4.txt
├── adir2
│   ├── afile1
│   ├── afile2
│   ├── afile3
│   └── afile4.txt
├── adir3
│   ├── afile1
│   ├── afile2
│   ├── afile3
│   └── afile4.txt
├── afile1
├── afile2
├── afile3
├── foo.test
```

This was the solution that worked for this scenario (which I believe is the more general case).

```
 $ find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' -exec zip -r test.zip {} +
```

#### Example

```
$ find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' -exec zip -r test.zip {} +
updating: adir1/afile1 (stored 0%)
updating: adir1/afile1.zip (stored 0%)
updating: adir1/afile2 (stored 0%)
updating: adir1/afile3 (stored 0%)
updating: adir1/afile4.txt (stored 0%)
updating: adir2/afile1 (stored 0%)
updating: adir2/afile2 (stored 0%)
updating: adir2/afile3 (stored 0%)
updating: adir2/afile4.txt (stored 0%)
updating: adir3/afile1 (stored 0%)
updating: adir3/afile2 (stored 0%)
updating: adir3/afile3 (stored 0%)
updating: adir3/afile4.txt (stored 0%)
updating: afile1 (stored 0%)
updating: afile2 (stored 0%)
updating: afile3 (stored 0%)
updating: foo.test (deflated 87%)
```

Comment: In which way did it not work? Note that that `find`-based solution will only work properly if the list of files is small enough that only one `zip` instance is run.